# MySQL database hangs but less CPU

Tags: c#, mysql, innodb, database-performance

I create an application for 30 concurrent users using C# and InnoDB of MySQL(mysql-5.1.35).

The size of database is more than 100M lines (~20GB). Most of data is come from 7 active table (2M lines/table) and 7 archive table (10M lines/table)

There are 1 or 2 users insert data into 7 active tables when other users just request to get data.

The problem comes when 30 users login and request data from active table and 1 user insert data. The request of 30 users is hang but the CPU is less than 30%

Here is the status when normal

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    1
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Bytes_received  606
Bytes_sent  23017
Com_admin_commands  9
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze 0
Com_backup_table    0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   1
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  0
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  0
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_load_master_data    0
Com_load_master_table   0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_restore_table   0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  2
Com_set_option  6
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_column_types   0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_new_master 0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    2
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 6
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  1
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  0
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connections 142
Created_tmp_disk_tables 0
Created_tmp_files   8
Created_tmp_tables  1
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  0
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    0
Handler_read_next   0
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   2
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   1
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   42434
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  3
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    4490
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   20528
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   2574
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  65536
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   6
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_seq   98
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    1431525332
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    35199
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   94800
Innodb_data_fsyncs  4875
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    694767616
Innodb_data_reads   42282
Innodb_data_writes  9253
Innodb_data_written 152594432
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  4490
Innodb_dblwr_writes 138
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   6664
Innodb_log_writes   4496
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    4599
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   5413376
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    162
Innodb_pages_read   42272
Innodb_pages_written    4490
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 0
Innodb_rows_inserted    10510
Innodb_rows_read    550961974
Innodb_rows_updated 2828
Key_blocks_not_flushed  1
Key_blocks_unused   459101
Key_blocks_used 205
Key_read_requests   35164673
Key_reads   6
Key_write_requests  126548
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Max_used_connections    106
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  23
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  60
Open_tables 467
Opened_files    1887
Opened_table_definitions    0
Opened_tables   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  52
Qcache_free_memory  15365784
Qcache_hits 2008
Qcache_inserts  830
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   11233
Qcache_queries_in_cache 254
Qcache_total_blocks 606
Queries 32566
Questions   18
Rpl_status  NULL
Select_full_join    0
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 1
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  0
Sort_rows   0
Sort_scan   0
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   336273
Table_locks_waited  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  26
Threads_connected   80
Threads_created 106
Threads_running 37
Uptime  751
Uptime_since_flush_status   751
```

And status when hang

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 7
Aborted_connects    1
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Bytes_received  1092
Bytes_sent  70715
Com_admin_commands  25
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze 0
Com_backup_table    0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   1
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  0
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  0
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_load_master_data    0
Com_load_master_table   0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_restore_table   0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  2
Com_set_option  6
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_column_types   0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_new_master 0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    4
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 17
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  3
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  0
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connections 212
Created_tmp_disk_tables 0
Created_tmp_files   8
Created_tmp_tables  3
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  0
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    0
Handler_read_next   0
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   288
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   285
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   43168
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  3
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    6479
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   19681
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   2687
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  65536
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   6
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_seq   98
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    1767873092
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    35830
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   123940
Innodb_data_fsyncs  8471
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    705630208
Innodb_data_reads   42945
Innodb_data_writes  14765
Innodb_data_written 220889088
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  6479
Innodb_dblwr_writes 219
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   9422
Innodb_log_writes   7880
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    8033
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   8506880
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    233
Innodb_pages_read   42935
Innodb_pages_written    6479
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 0
Innodb_rows_inserted    13180
Innodb_rows_read    675335200
Innodb_rows_updated 4887
Key_blocks_not_flushed  1
Key_blocks_unused   459101
Key_blocks_used 205
Key_read_requests   53083682
Key_reads   6
Key_write_requests  161420
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 10.499000
Max_used_connections    106
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  23
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  60
Open_tables 654
Opened_files    2400
Opened_table_definitions    0
Opened_tables   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  58
Qcache_free_memory  14514616
Qcache_hits 2534
Qcache_inserts  1114
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   14164
Qcache_queries_in_cache 306
Qcache_total_blocks 717
Queries 46866
Questions   33
Rpl_status  NULL
Select_full_join    0
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 3
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  0
Sort_rows   0
Sort_scan   0
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   624724
Table_locks_waited  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  6
Threads_connected   95
Threads_created 106
Threads_running 55
Uptime  1294
Uptime_since_flush_status   1294
```

[image]
Please help me to find out the problem.

Comment: What does *insert data* means? How does that insert statement goes? is it a bulk update/insert? How many rows are inserted in one transaction?

Comment: Insert data mean the the user load file that contain ~ 100 tupes of data. Each tupe has more than 800 fields to insert into application ==> ~1K rows/1 transaction

Comment: That `SELECT` is inefficient; let's see the complete query, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  From those, we can probably uncork the problem.

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` is more useful than `SHOW STATUS`, which defaults to `SESSION`.  Also, `SHOW VARIABLES` has important information.